# Definition of Cylindrical Symmetry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, cylindrical-coordinates

In cylindrical coordinates I have a function $f(\rho,z,\theta)$. What does it mean for $f$ to be cylindrically symmetric? I can't find any precise definition online. My guess is that $f(\rho,z,\theta)=g(\rho)$.

Comment: You mean $z=g(\rho)$? It is correct for non-spiral surfaces of revolution by rotation of the meridian, $g$ is inverse function of $ f ... g^{-1} (z) =f(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is my understanding of the term and it appears on all sorts of pages that come up when you Google it, like

http://www.physicsbootcamp.org/Electric-Field-for-Cylindrical-Symmetry.html

However, it looks like Wikipedia and a number of other sources would call anything of the form $g(\rho,z)$ cylindrically symmetric, saying that cylindrical symmetry merely means "no change when rotating about one axis"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry

Comment: I'd use it to mean "independent of $\theta$ or $z$", too. Since that's exactly the transformations which leave an (unbounded) cylinder unchanged.

Comment: No, when independent of $z$ we have spirals in a radial plane.

Comment: @Narasimham well it could be spirals, certainly, but it doesn't have to be, does it? It could be any two-dimensional function, e.g., Hofstadter's butterfly, as long as it just kept translating uniformly in the $z$-direction. EDIT: Oh, I think I see the confusion: you're describing something where $\rho$ is a function of $\theta$, I think the poster is indicating a scenario in which $f$ is a function of $\rho$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Is it not a 2D prismatic non-rotational fractal pattern?

Comment: @Narasimham yes, the butterfly is a 2D fractal pattern without continuous rotational symmetry. My point is that a function $f(\rho,\theta)$ could look like anything in the 2D plane described by $\rho,\theta$, it doesn't have to look like spirals.

Comment: The OP asked about $f( \rho,z, \theta).$  Is there a $z$ dependence or not?

Comment: @Narasimham in "$f(\rho,z,\theta)$" there clearly is a $z$-dependence. You've just written one. The OP also asks whether a $z$-dependence is permitted when a function is "cylindrically symmetric". Per my answer, this depends on which source you consult for your definition. None of that has much to do with my comment to you, which was simply that your statement, "No, when independent of z we have spirals in a radial plane" is not, in general, true: there is no need that the function be in any way spiral-shaped.

Comment: Comments are contradictory, it need not be any spiral shaped always. was only an example. We take the moderator's suggestion for next,  if you please...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is *rotational symmetry*, referring to $(\rho,\theta, z)$ coordinates of the *surface and lines drawn* on a surface of revolution... the situation is a.k.a axi-symmetry:

[image]

A *meridian*  $\rho= f(z)$ (red) is rotated around  an *axis of symmetry* $\rho=0$ along which $z$ is an independent variable. Shown are black circumferential lines.

The meridian is defined

$$\rho= f(z)$$

To locate a point on this surface of revolution we resolve/project $\rho$ further onto $(x,y)$ axes.

The projection enables definition of axi-symmetry *for parametrization* of any point *on a surface of revolution* in the cylindrical coordinate system using two parameters:

$$ \{\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin\theta,f^{-1}(\rho)\}  $$

where $ (\rho, \theta)$ can be *functions of a fourth parameter* say arc length or time for a 3D *surface parametric form*. This form defines non-meridional spiral situation:

$$ \{\rho (s)  \cos \theta(s),\; \rho (s)\sin\theta(s),\; f^{-1}\rho(s)\}. $$

$$\{ \rho (t)  \cos \theta(t),\; \rho (t)\sin\theta(t), \;f^{-1}\rho(t)\}  $$

This can be also written as a special useful  case for as 3D *parametric line* with a single parameter for the non- meridional situation:

$$\{ \rho (\theta)  \cos \theta,\; \rho (\theta)\sin\theta, \;f^{-1}\rho(\theta)\}.  $$